# Java Array Parsing

Tags: java, arrays, parsing

Lets say I have a string array called ar1,
ar1[x] is "Harry Potter"

Now lets say I have another string array called ar2,
I want ar2[x] to equal "Harry". How would I do this?

Here is something I tried, it did not work.

```
String ar2[] = new String[10];
int x = 0;        
while(x<9){
        ar2[x] = ar1[x].split(" ").toString();
        x++;
        System.out.println(ar2[x]);}}}
```

the out put was 9 null's.

Comment: Your problem is that you print value after incrementing index.

Comment: now if i wanted "Potter" how would i do this? thankyou

Comment: `ar1[x].split(" ")[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're calling `toString()` on a String array.
The 'split()' method [Returns a String array](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)), and what you want is the first element in the array resulting from the split.

It looks like you want something like this:

```
    String ar2[] = new String[ar1.length]; //better if this is not hard coded to 10
    int x = 0;        
    while(x < ar1.length){
            String[] temp = ar1[x].split(" ");
            ar2[x] = temp[0];
            x++; //Moved in initial edit to fix null printing
     }

     //moved printing code out of loop where populating array occurs 
     for (int i = 0; i < ar2.length; i++){
            System.out.println(ar2[i]);
     }
```

Comment: Thanks @Sasha Salauyou, fixed.

Comment: this also prints just null

Comment: thank you guys a simple error by me ): thank you sasha and daniel

Comment: might add a note that the `x++` had to moved.